# How to set background color as transparent in CARTO Mobile SDK (Xamarin iOS/Android)?

Tags: xamarin, cartodb

I'm now using CARTO Xamarin Mobile SDK as mobile app's map engine.
For may use case, I want to make the background color of CARTO MapView to transparent.
Anyone know how to do it?

The reason of this requirement is, I want to put another View in back of MapView.
The back view is not static image but dynamic, and I want to show it if map tiles are missing.
So background must be transparent..

Regards,
Kohei

[image: I want to make transparent here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with live SDK version, this feature is added to CARTO Mobile SDK 4.1.0, currently in development.

See more: https://github.com/CartoDB/mobile-sdk/issues/88

Update: SDK 4.1.0 alpha version can now be taken from *nuget* (for [iOS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CartoMobileSDK.iOS/) or [Android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CartoMobileSDK.Android)), just enable "Pre-release" versions in nuget package loader and pick 4.1.0-alpha-8 or newer for **CartoMobileSDK**.

Comment: Thanks @JaakL, and I'm a man who reported this request to issue 88.
Anyway thank you for implement this so quickly!

Comment: And one more, I make another question about CARTO Mobile SDK license.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43219453/carto-xamarin-mobile-sdk-is-allowed-to-use-with-free-license
Would you please give comment for this?