# CARTO Xamarin Mobile SDK is allowed to use with FREE license?

Tags: xamarin, cartodb

I believe, one before, CARTO Xamarin Mobile SDK was activated only with CARTO enterprise license.

But now, I don't find such limitation in CARTO's pricing page.
https://carto.com/pricing/

This means, CARTO Xamarin Mobile SDK is also allowed to use with FREE license?

Comment: This question really belongs on the third party's website.

Comment: SO is not a site for legal advice.  You need to contact the vendor if you have questions about their license.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about licensing.

Comment: Apologies I forgot SO is not for licensing question.. I vote for close by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CARTO Mobile SDK pricing is in https://carto.com/pricing/engine/ page, under "Mobile apps" switch. Free option covers all the out of box platforms: iOS, Android, Windows 10 UWP and Xamarin. In addition you can develop also JS-based apps with Cordova or React Native, using native plug-in wrappers. *Note: I'm head of mobile at CARTO.*